# How to find out which resource not found while publishing message to Google Cloud Pub/Sub?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am very new to Google Cloud. I want to accomplish message publishing to Google Cloud Pub/Sub service from my nodejs app. However, I received an error below while publishing the message:

```
Received error while publishing: Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=193060).
```

I cannot figure `resource=193060` out. What is 193060?

***Here is my *server.js*:***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}))

// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
const topicName = 'projects/codeway-312008/topics/codeway-log';
const data2 = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'event',
    app_id: 'com.codeway.test',
    session_id: 'vIfEMi9kJW',
    event_name: 'about',
    event_time: 1598196427881,
    page: 'settings',
    country: 'US',
    region: 'New Jersey',
    city: 'Newark',
    user_id: '9t0lrnYLQr'
});


async function publishMessage() {
    // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data2);

    try {
        const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
        console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Received error while publishing: ${error}`);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
}


publishMessage();
```

***My topic:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the missing resource is the schema associated with the topic. It was probably deleted after the topic was created. The error message needs to be cleaned up to make this more clear and so the Cloud Pub/Sub team will be sure to do that.

Comment: However, message detail must be more clear I think.